# My calculator isn't calling upon variables properly

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm writing a calculator in java that has memory to store variables. It shows the list of variables properly, adds and subtracts, and defines variables, but whenever I try to do something like a = b + 1, it treats b as if it is 0, giving 'a' a value of 1.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> variables = new ArrayList<>();

    while(scan.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = scan.nextLine();
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");

        if(!Character.isDigit(tokens[0].charAt(0)) && !line.equals("clear") && !line.equals("var"))
        {
            int value = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++)
            {
                if(tokens.length==1)
                {   
                    if(variables.contains(tokens[0]))
                    {
                        printAnswer(values.get(variables.indexOf(tokens[0])));
                    }
                    else if(!line.equals("quit"))
                    {
                        int width = 4 + tokens[0].length();
                        System.out.printf("%" + width + "s is not defined\n", tokens[0]);
                    }
                    break;
                }
                if(tokens.length==3)
                {
                    value = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                    printAnswer(value);
                    if(variables.contains(tokens[0]))
                    {
                        values.set(variables.indexOf(tokens[0]), value);
                        variables.set(variables.indexOf(tokens[0]), tokens[0]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        values.add(value);
                        variables.add(tokens[0]);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                else if(tokens[i].charAt(0) == '+')
                {
                    value = addition(tokens, value, variables, values);
                    printAnswer(value);

                    if(variables.contains(tokens[0]))
                    {
                        values.set(variables.indexOf(tokens[0]), value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        values.add(value);
                        variables.add(tokens[0]);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                else if(tokens[i].charAt(0) == '-')
                {
                    value = subtraction(tokens, value);
                    printAnswer(value);

                    if(variables.contains(tokens[0]))
                    {
                        values.set(variables.indexOf(tokens[0]), value);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        values.add(value);
                        variables.add(tokens[0]);
                    }
                    break;
                }

                else if(i==tokens.length-1)
                {
                    System.out.println("No operation");
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }       

        if(Character.isDigit(tokens[0].charAt(0)))
        {
            int value = 0;
            for(int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++)
            {
                if(tokens.length==1)
                {
                    value = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
                    printAnswer(value);
                    break;
                }

                else if(tokens[i].charAt(0) == '+')
                {
                    value = addition(tokens, value, variables, values);
                    printAnswer(value);
                }

                else if(tokens[i].charAt(0) == '-')
                {
                    value = subtraction(tokens, value);
                    printAnswer(value);
                }
            }
        }

        if(line.equals("clear"))
        {
            clear(variables, values);
        }

        if(line.equals("var"))
        {
            variableList(variables, values);
        }       

        else if(line.equals("quit"))
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

public static int addition(String[] a, int b, ArrayList<String> c, ArrayList<Integer> d)
{
    for(String item : a)
    {
        int i=0;
        if(Character.isDigit(item.charAt(0)))
        {
            int val = Integer.parseInt(item);
            b = b + val;
            i++;
        }
        else if(Character.isLetter(item.charAt(0)) && i!=0)
        {
            int val = d.get(c.indexOf(item));
            b = b + val;
        }   
    }
    return b;
}

public static int subtraction(String[] a, int b)
{
    int i=0;
    for(String item : a)
    {
        if(Character.isDigit(item.charAt(0)))
        {
            int val = Integer.parseInt(item);
            if(i==0)
            {
                b = b + val;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                b = b - val;
            }
        }
    }
    return b;
}

public static void clear(ArrayList<String> a, ArrayList<Integer> b)
{
    a.clear();
    b.clear();
}

public static void variableList(ArrayList<String> a, ArrayList<Integer> b)
{

    for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
    {
        int width = 4 + a.get(i).length();
        System.out.printf("%" + width + "s: %d\n", a.get(i), b.get(i));
    }
}

public static void printAnswer(int a)
{
    int width = 3;
    Integer valueToString = a;
    String valueString = valueToString.toString();
    for(int j=0; j<=valueString.length(); j++)
    {
        width++;
    }
    System.out.printf("%" + width + "d\n",a);
}
```

[image: Problem]

Main problem is within the addition method

Comment: Please use comment. It will help us help

Comment: Yes, describe for what are the arrays used in the `addition` method used for.

Comment: What others are saying. It is faster if you tell us how your program works. Otherwise we have to sit down and figure it out and (presumably) you already know. It looks like 200+ lines and the problem could be anywhere.

Comment: In the body of the loop: if(tokens.length==3), you only look at two of the tokens, token[0] and token[2]. But you want to set the first one to the sum of the other 2

Comment: My main concern is in the addition method, int val = d.get(c.indexOf(item)); isn't producing the correct value. It seems to be getting 0. It should be getting the value that corresponds with the variable given, since it checks the index of the variable and uses the index in the values array (which is parallel with the variable array)

Comment: Your addition method isn't actually trying to parse 'b' at all, it skips over it completely.  Note the `i!=0` condition which stays in play for the entire loop

Comment: i!=0 is true after the first if statement happens because it contains i++, correct? Oh wow, nevermind. Stupid mistake. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I moved int i=0 outside of the loop, so now when the loop is activated, shouldn't the second iteration use the else if statement? I would then equal 1

Comment: It's pointless to analyze defects in this code when the entire approach is wrong. This code will never cope with operator precedence or parentheses correctly. You can't do this without an operand stack. You need to look up 'recursive descent expression parser' or the Djikstra shunthing-yard algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I could explain to you why your program is setting 'a' to 1 when you enter the command "a + b + 1", but this will not really help you.  You need to take a hard look at your code, step through it a bit, and see if you can structure it more logically, because right now it is just a bunch of statements strung together that do not actually define any meaningful behavior.  Writing comments and using more meaningful variable names helps a lot.

A few notes on this:

- Never in your loop do you check for the '=' sign.  This means that the commands:

  "a = b + 1"

  "a + b + 1"

  ...get processed exactly the same way, assigning a value of 1 to 'a'
- Your addition and subtraction methods do not account for position whatsoever.  This means that the first operator encountered is applied to all tokens in the string.  I.e:

  "a c + d - 3 - - x 5"

  ...is exactly the same as:

  "a c + d + + + 3 5 x"

  (Note that both of these strings are utter nonsense)

Try using a debugger to step through your code and see what it is doing.  That will help you a lot.